# What Iterator.next() method do inside a for statement when used with java.util.Queue?

Tags: java, for-loop, iterator, queue

For example:

```java
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Queue<String> names = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList("First", "Middle", "Last"));
        System.out.println("Queue before the loop: " + names);

        System.out.println("Printing loop...");
        for (Iterator<String> i = names.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
            String name = i.next();
            System.out.println(name);
        }

        System.out.println("Queue after the loop: " + names);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Queue before the loop: [First, Middle, Last]
Printing loop...
First
Middle
Last
Queue after the loop: [First, Middle, Last]
```

I know how the next() method traverse the *LinkedList*. But when it is called on a *Queue.iterator()* like, `i.next()` what does it do? 
As you can see from the output it haven't removed any element from the queue. 
*which I thought would be the case, since Queue only have `remove()/poll()`.*

Comment: Why do you think it would remove any element? You never called `remove()`. You can think of an `iterator` as a pointer, that is pointing at specific element of the collection. When you call `i.next()`, the pointer moves by one and points on another element.

Comment: @Amongalen Beacuse I am assuming `Queue` only have `remove()/poll()` methods to get all of the stored values/objects. Therefore, how can an *iterator* of a `Queue object` traverse it without changing the `Queue`, *`names`*?           Also, if `next()` uses a pointer on a `Queue object` what is the method it uses to get the n_th element ?

Answer (score 1):

`Iterator` is simply used to iterate over a Collection. In this case, you could have used a for-each for the same result:

```
for(String name : names){
  System.out.println(name);
}
```

Based on your question however, I assume you want to iterate over the `Queue`, ***popping*** and printing each item in FIFO order (hence the use of your `LinkedList`). In that case, you may simply want to loop `names.size()` amount of times, and calling `.remove()` to pop an item each iteration, like this:

```
for(int n = names.size(); n > 0; n--){
  String name = names.remove();
  System.out.println(name);
}
```

Output:

```
Queue before the loop: [First, Middle, Last]
Printing loop...
First
Middle
Last
Queue after the loop: []
```

[**Try it online.**](https://tio.run/##jU9NT8MwDL33V1g9pUAjznRU4sKpk0A7Ig7Z6o10aVIlbtFA@@3FaaWpCIHwxYn9PvwaNai8qY/jqNvOeYKGB7InbeRVkSQ7o0KAtdL2MwGurt8avYNAirgNTtfQ8lJsyGt7eHkFlc3AWM899riaVyVY1WKAe7D4DpW2R6wrHWhVigfv1SlIFeJfpI/aB0pvIF3rujYYX5XiSZYVF@XNKRC20vUkO1YnY0U6ucEW984j0BuCca67gxSuZ2um/8l/ig@@dOJJKdOFH2sK3oKN90cxGfQHiqzgSQm33PJ8EXyymGJP6AvJY@uGSPuO/HlMhC9Q5@QfydWe0P8SfBY5j@MX)

---

EDIT: To explain a bit more of what's going on for the `.iterator()`:

If we look at [the source code of the `Iterator`](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/util/Iterator-source.html), we can see it's an interface. Each Collection-implementation will have its own individual Iterator implementation.
Looking at [the source code of the `Queue`](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/43stack/Queue.java.html), the `iterator()` method is this:

```java
/**
 * Returns an iterator that iterates over the items in this queue in FIFO order.
 *
 * @return an iterator that iterates over the items in this queue in FIFO order
 */
public Iterator<Item> iterator() {
    return new ListIterator();
}

// an iterator, doesn't implement remove() since it's optional
private class ListIterator implements Iterator<Item> {
    private Node current = first;  // node containing current item

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return current != null;
    }

    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    public Item next() {
        if (!hasNext()) throw new NoSuchElementException();
        Item item = current.item;
        current = current.next;
        return item;
    }
}
```

As you can see, it stores the `Node first` of Queue as its `current` when the `ListIterator` is created in the `iterator()` method.
In the actual `next()`-method, it uses neither the `remove()` nor `poll()` methods of the Queue (nor `get()`..), so the items aren't actually popped. Instead, it simply stores the current Node temporarily with `Item item = current.item`; then updates the `current` Node to the next one with `current = current.next`; after which it will return that temporary `item`.

Comment: I know I can use your suggestion and I have used it. I'm wondering how this java native enhanced for loop does it, though. In [here(documentation for enhanced for loop)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2) , it says they use the `iterator.next()` method to get the element. But, how could that be possible since `java.util.Queue` doesn't have a `get()` method.

Comment: @LahiruEkanayake I've added some clarifications at the bottom. The `Queue` (and other Collection-implementations) each have their own implementation of the `iterator()` method, using the `Iterator`-interface. For the Queue in particular, it simply keeps track of the current item in a local variable using the `Node first` initially with `Item current = first;`, and going to the next one in line inside the `next()` method implementation with `current = current.next;`. I'm not sure where you've read that it uses the `get()` method, but the `iterator()` and thus its `next()` differs per Collection

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong. I found that, since `names` is a `LinkedList` object `names.iterator()` returns from an iterator() implementation on the `AbstractSequentialList` class (which is the immediate super class of `LinkedList` class). After tracking that iterator I found [this](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/share/classes/java/util/AbstractList.java#l354) is the `next()` method implementation that iterator uses. You can clearly see on the given source code it uses `get()` method.

Comment: @LahiruEkanayake Hmm, I don't see anything wrong with your deduction, but I don't see how `Queue` is relevant. You're indeed correct that `LinkedList` uses the `iterator()` of `AbstractSequentialList`; which in turn uses the `listIterator()` that `LinkedList` implements again (returning `listIterator(0)`); which uses `listIterator(int index)` of `AbstractList` (as you had already linked); which indeed uses a `get(int index)` method. And that `get(int)` method can be found as abstract method in the `AbstractList`, and as actual implementation in the `LinkedList`. The `Queue` is irrelevant here.

Comment: Sorry if my explanation in the answer is confusing, since you were asking about `Queue` directly. The `Queue` in `Queue names = new LinkedList` could have been any higher class/interface of `LinkedList`, but the `iterator()` will still use the one of `LinkedList`, including all its methods (so including `get(int index)`). Whether you use `Queue`, `Collection`, `List`, `AbstractList`, or even Java 10+ `var` isn't really important, since the actual instance is of type `LinkedList`, so it will use its `iterator()` and `get(int)` methods. At least, that's how I understood it.

Comment: No @Kevin. We were wrong the whole time. Finally I figured the entire process of calling `names.iterator().next()` . You also can see the *call stack* using a debugger (any decent java IDE has one). To my knowledge `names.iterator()` would return from an **overridden method** situated [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/share/classes/java/util/LinkedList.java#l864) in *LinkedList* class. Hope the benefit you gained outweighs the troubles you had. <br/> I repeat, "that son of a gun **overridden method** was there the whole time" deceiving us :P.

Answer (score 0):

> Since `names` is a *LinkedList* object and *LinkedList* does't have
>   any `iterator()` method in it, `names.iterator()` would call
>   [that method in
>   *AbstractSequentialList*](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/share/classes/java/util/AbstractSequentialList.java#l238)
>   (immediate super class of *LinkedList*).
>
> However, by tracking the call stack *(can be done easily through a GUI debugger of any decent java IDE)* when initializing `i = names.iterator()` one can easily see it calls the method `listIterator(0)` method [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/share/classes/java/util/AbstractList.java#l299). Eventhough *AbstractList* has it's own implementation of `listIterator(int index)`, *LinkedList* has [overriden that same method](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/share/classes/java/util/LinkedList.java#l864) ;

Segment of *LinkedList.java* :

```
package java.util;

public class LinkedList<E>
    extends AbstractSequentialList<E>
    implements List<E>, Deque<E>, Cloneable, java.io.Serializable
{   
    public ListIterator<E> listIterator(int index) {
            checkPositionIndex(index);
            return new ListItr(index);
    }
    private class ListItr implements ListIterator<E> {
        private Node<E> lastReturned = null;
        private Node<E> next;
        private int nextIndex;
        private int expectedModCount = modCount;
        ListItr(int index) {
            // assert isPositionIndex(index);
            next = (index == size) ? null : node(index);
            nextIndex = index;
        }
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return nextIndex < size;
        }
        public E next() {
            checkForComodification();
            if (!hasNext())
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            lastReturned = next;
            next = next.next;
            nextIndex++;
            return lastReturned.item;
        }
    *
    *   (code contraction...)
    *
        final void checkForComodification() {
                if (modCount != expectedModCount)
                    throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
            }
    }
}
```

> Hence, obviously `names.iterator()` would return an object through `return new ListItr(index)`, which is an inner class of *LinkedList*.
>
> Now we can clearly see when calling `i.next()`, it actually calls the `next()` method in the inner class ***ListItr***. Also it uses the class variable;

```
private Node<E> next;
```

> to track, to where the iterator is pointing next.
>
> This comes into play when considering the performance of the [enhanced for loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2).

Segment of Oracle docs for *enhance-for-loop*s :

```
for (I #i = Expression.iterator(); #i.hasNext(); ) {
    VariableModifiersopt TargetType Identifier = (TargetType) #i.next();
    Statement
}
```

> As you can see this uses the `#i.next()` method and since `names`(in the original question's example) is a variable of type ***Queue***, one can in-the-dark assume `#i.next()` in the enhanced-for-loop uses [this](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/share/classes/java/util/AbstractList.java#l354) implementation which is in *AbstractList* and it questionably uses some `get(int index)` method, hence poor performance (a poor,unfortunate guy like me, did the same deduction and caught up in a hay-stack of code. LOL).
>
> On that false deduction I asked this question in this forum and after digging deeper for several days, now I can see there are **no any performance reduction**(not that I know of) when **using an enhanced-for-loop to iterate over a *LinkedList* object** due to the fact,
>
> > that *iterator object*(`#i`) uses a variable `Node<E> next` to keep the reference to the next object in-order to use in the *enhanced-for-loop* 's next iteration.